# What is the difference between "spark-shell" and "spark-shell --master=local"?

Tags: apache-spark

Can someone help me in understanding what is the difference if I open Spark using the following two commands?

1. `spark-shell`
2. `spark-shell --master=local`

Comment: `spark-shell` will utilize all the cores you have in your machine as local[*] whereas `spark-shell --master=local` will utilize only one core of your local machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ramesh!

Comment: Please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start spark shell without `--master` option, then **all the cores of your local machine is utilized** as you can see in the log that it starts with following message

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1519264959885).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
```

But when you start with `--master local` option, **it starts utilizing only one core of your local machine** as you can see in the log

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local, app id = local-1519265031949).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
```